# CZMQ: Getting started on Raspberry-Pi

Tags: c++, sockets, raspberry-pi, zeromq

I made one simple `client-server` application on desktop PC and ran it successfully while making client and server on same PC.

Then i cross compiled the app to run it on raspberry. When i am running this app on raspberry, both client and server on raspberry, it is working perfectly. I can see the sent and received messages.

Now i made PC as server and raspberry as client but i can't see the received messages. Here is my code.

**PC Side Code:**

```
zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new ();
void *reader = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_PULL);
int rc = zsocket_connect (reader, "tcp://PC-IP:5555");
printf("wait for a message...\n");
while(1)
    {
        char *message = zstr_recv (reader);
        Sleep(10);
        printf("Message: %s",message);
    }
zctx_destroy (&ctx);
```

**Raspberry Side Code:**

```
zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new ();
void *writer = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_PUSH);
int rc = zsocket_bind (writer, "tcp://PC-IP:5555");
while(1)
    {
        cout<<"sending................."<<endl;
        zstr_send (writer, "HELLO");
    }
zsocket_destroy (ctx, writer);
```

How can i make it work?

Comment: You should always bind to the local IP address (or 0.0.0.0 for all ipv4 interfaces or 0::0 for all ipv4/ipv6 interfaces) and connect to the remote IP address, not the other way around...

Comment: @Elijan9, if you write this comment as answer, i will approve it. Your comment solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server should always *bind* to its own interface (either its local IP address or `0.0.0.0` for all IPv4 interfaces or `0::0` for both IPv4 and IPv6).

A client should always *connect* to the remote IP address.

Since you want your PC to be a server pulling messages from the Raspberry Pi *client*, I think you should use the following:

**PC Side Code**

```
zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new ();
void *reader = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_PULL);
int rc = zsocket_bind (reader, "tcp://PC-IP:5555");
printf("wait for a message...\n");
while(1)
    {
        char *message = zstr_recv (reader);
        Sleep(10);
        printf("Message: %s",message);
    }
zctx_destroy (&ctx);
```

**Raspberry Side Code**

```
zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new ();
void *writer = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_PUSH);
int rc = zsocket_connect (writer, "tcp://PC-IP:5555");
while(1)
    {
        cout<<"sending................."<<endl;
        zstr_send (writer, "HELLO");
    }
zsocket_destroy (ctx, writer);
```

Of course you could also run the Raspberry Pi as pushing *server*, and the PC side as pulling *client*. In that case you could use:

```
...
int rc = zsocket_connect (reader, "tcp://raspberrypi-ip:5555");
...
```

and:

```
...
int rc = zsocket_bind (writer, "tcp://raspberrypi-ip:5555");
...
```